# Excel macro to convert a one - one relation to a one - many

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns - one is Group Name and the other is user which looks something like this:

[image: Input]

I need to convert this to show all groups as column headers and all users under the respective group as follows:

[image: Output]

The macro is to run on a large number of groups with no such limit to number of users. If there are a 100 groups, the macro is to create a 100 columns and list users under the respective groups.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a coding service website. Please show us, what you have tried so far in a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help.

Comment: I have no idea how to get started with this piece - i tried vlookups - but didnt seem to be a feasible solution given the input is dynamic. Any direction with a macro based solution would help - I would share a snippet - but like I said - i need some help to get started - would appreciate any input.

Comment: Would it be allowed to sort by column A? This would make it a lot easier.

Comment: il have the data sorted as a step 1 - do let me know what you have in mind - thanks :)

Comment: Bulid a loop through all used rows in your data and copy the user names to the first column until the group name changes. Then switch the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the source data is sorted by GroupName.
2. Loop through all data rows.
3. Every time the GroupName changes, move to a new column and write the header
4. Write the user to the current destination column

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSource")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataOutput")

    'sort data by GroupName
    With wsSrc.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A:B")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row in column A
    LastRow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim CurrentGroup As String

    Dim DestCol As Long, DestRow As Long 'counters for destination column and row
    DestCol = 0 'destination column

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow 'loop through all data rows
        If wsSrc.Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> CurrentGroup Then 'if GroupName changed …
            CurrentGroup = wsSrc.Cells(iRow, 1).Value 'remember new group name
            DestCol = DestCol + 1 'move destination 1 column further
            DestRow = 1 'start at the top in this new column
            wsDest.Cells(DestRow, DestCol).Value = CurrentGroup 'write header (GroupName) of new group into the column
        End If

        'write user …
        DestRow = DestRow + 1 'move to the next free row
        wsDest.Cells(DestRow, DestCol).Value = wsSrc.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for your help - will start with a snippet the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of this answer data included in Sheet1 and separate in Groups in Sheet2.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim GroupName As String
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LC2 As Long
    Dim LR2 As Long
    Dim Exist As Boolean

    LC = Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LR = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        Exist = True
        GroupName = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value

        If LC = 1 And Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
            Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Value = GroupName
            Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Else
            LC2 = Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For j = 1 To LC2
                If GroupName = Sheet2.Cells(1, j).Value Then
                    LR2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheet2.Cells(LR2 + 1, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    Exist = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                   Exist = False
                End If
            Next j
            If Exist = False Then
                Sheet2.Cells(1, LC2 + 1).Value = GroupName
                Sheet2.Cells(1, LC2 + 1).Offset(2, 0).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you realize that you used 2 different worksheet naming systems? `Worksheets("Sheet2")` uses the name on the tab but `Sheet1.` uses the VBA name of a sheet. `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `Sheet1.` can be 2 completely different worksheets. Don't mix the naming systems stick to one.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have revise the code.could you please provide a feedback?

Comment: Well, there was no need to remove the `With` statement, you could have changed it to `With Sheet2`. I just wanted to make sure that you realize that `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `Sheet1` can be different sheets, because the VBA name of a sheet can be a different one than the "tab" name in Excel.

Comment: ok to make sure that everything works correct i use the same syntax for each cell.